# Proving continuity of two functions, one from a subspace of Y and other from the space Y

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

The question goes as follows

> Let X and Y be topological spaces, and let f:X $\rightarrow$Y Define Z = {f(x)|X $\in$ X} $\subseteq$ Y to be the image of the function f, and equip Z with a topology as a subspace of Y. Define $\overline{f}$: X $\rightarrow$ Z by $\overline{f}$(x) = f(x). Show that f is continous if and only if $\overline{f}$ is continous.

So I started with f and assuming it to be continuous which implies that the open sets of X map to open sets of Y. But I could not relate it to $\overline{f}$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: How does an open set in $Z$ look like?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy would it be the intersection of Z and open sets of Y?

Comment: continuity doesn't mean the we map open sets to open sets! You're confused with open maps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions between two topological spaces, $f$ being continuous means that the preimage of any open set in $Y$ is open in $X$, not the other way around as suggested in your post. So if $f$ is continuous and $A\subset Z$ is any open set in the subspace topology, we have some open set $B\subset Y$ such that $A=B\cap Z$. Thus $\bar{f}^{-1}(A)=f^{-1}(B\cap Z)=f^{-1}(B)$, which is open by continuity of $f$. For the other way around you can argue similarly.

Comment: I still don't get how $\overline{f} inverse of (B intersection Z) is open

Comment: @AdityaEkbote: that's because it equals the inverse from $f$, which is open, by the definition of continuity: the INVERSE(or PREIMAGE) of any open set is open,not the image.

Comment: No I mean how do know if B intersection Z is open. I am clear on the fact that B is open but we don't know if Z is open in Y so how will B intersection Z be open or maybe I am again messing up with the definition? I am really confused

Comment: @AdityaEkbote: I've added that in my answer.

Comment: Ohh ok got thanks

Comment: @AdityaEkbote: you can select it as accepted to let people know your question is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f=\bar{f}$ as the two functions are comprised of precisely the same ordered pairs. Moreover, given open $U\subseteq Y$ then $f^{-1}[U]=f^{-1}[U\cap Z]$ and therefore $f$ is continuous iff $\bar{f}$ is as well. That is, $f$ is continuous iff it is continuous with respect to the subspace topology on $Z$.

Comment: What do you mean by the same ordered pairs?

Comment: @AdityaEkbote. Remember, a function is a set of ordered pairs.

Comment: Oh as in like (x,y) for x in X and y in Y?

Comment: @AdityaEkbote. Exactly. By definition.

Comment: @AdityaEkbote. Essentially, the OP asks to show that $f$ is continuous iff it is continuous with respect to the subspace topology on $\text{Im}(f)$.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial set theory and logic tells us that (because $Z=f[X]$):

$$f^{-1}[O]= (\overline{f})^{-1}[O \cap Z]\tag{1}$$

for any $O \subseteq Y$.

If $f$ is continuous and $O'$ is open in $Z$, by the subspace topology definition $O'=O \cap Z$ for some open $O \subseteq Y$. Then $(1)$ tells us that $(\overline{f})^{-1}[O']$ is open in $X$. So $\overline{f}$ is continuous.

If $\overline{f}$ is continuous and $O$ is open in $Y$, $(1)$ *also* tells us that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open in $X$ and $f$ is continuous.

---

If you know about the universal property of initial (aka induced) topologies: if $i: f[X]\to Y$ is the canonical embedding (that induces the subspace topology) then $f=i \circ \overline{f}$ by definition and one implication follows from the fact that the composition of continuous maps is continuous and the other from the universal property of $i$.